# Bootstrap 3: a responsive table inside an iFrame

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and have issues with a table inside an iFrame or any contents. I want the iFrame contents to be treated as part of the page.
I've already removed the iFrame borders just to be clear.

So for instance if the iFrame is 1000 pixels in width the contents inner page width should also be `1000px` @ 100%.

I am using Bootstrap 3.

[image]

As you can see in the example, the iFrame has a scrollbar as it thinks its page size is 1920 width.

```
<?php if(login_check($mysqli)==true): ?>
<body>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Clients</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select>
            <option value="name">First Name</option>
            <option value="surname">Surname</option>
            <option value="company">Company</option>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id ="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Account</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Street</th>
                    <th>type</th>
                    <th>Suburb</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $clients_list = "SELECT * FROM clients_table";
            $details = $mysqli->query($clients_list);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($details))  {
                echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_account'].'" id="_account'.$row['_account'].'" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_first'].' " id="_first'.$row['_id'].'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_surname'].'"id="_surname'.$row['_id'].'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_phone'].'"id="_phone'.$row['_id'].'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_unit'].'" id="_unit'.$row['_id'].'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_street'].'" id="_street'.$row['_id'].'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_type'].'" id="_type'.$row['_id'].'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_suburb'].'"id="_suburb'.$row['_id'].'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['_email'].'"id="_email'.$row['_id'].'"/></td>  
                    </tr>';
            }
            ?>          
            </tbody>
        </table>                                                        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for that in bootstrap.css

Please try it.

```
.table-responsive {
  min-height: .01%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;       
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

As far as i know if the page that is being loaded in your iframe is responsive then you will have no problem at all.

So if you set height & width at 100% then it will "fit" exactly in the iframe, making it look like part of your primary webpage.